# How to simulate equivalent circuit of a transformer referred to primary side in Matlab?

Tags: circuit-analysis, transformer, three-phase, matlab

I was given an assignment to demonstrate a three-phase transformer simulation using Matlab Simulink. I have to demonstrate the simulations of simplified per phase equivalent circuit of a three-phase transformer referred to the primary side and demonstrate the simulations of simplified per phase equivalent circuit of a three-phase transformer referred to the secondary side. But I have no clue on what I should actually do in the Matlab simulation. My question is how do I simulate the below equivalent circuit in Matlab simulink or am I doing it wrong?

[image: equivalent circuit referred to primary]

Comment: Have you tried asking Matlab support forums?